# How to constrain the type of Generator.Element in a Protocol extending SequenceType

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

Assume I'm writing a social media crawler that handle's multiple accounts (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

I define a few protocols for messages (`Message` has display-name and message body, `Timestamped` has a timestamp, `Forwarded` has the original message ID etc).

I then define a protocol for a source of messages, which I've currently written

```
protocol MessageSource : SequenceType {
    associatedtype MessageType : Timestamped

    func messages (since : NSDate) -> Generator
}
```

The idea is I can get the `n` most recent messages by writing `msgSource.take(n)` and get all messages since a date `d` by writing `msgSource.messages(since : d)`

My question is, how do I constrain the `Generator.Element` inherited from `SequenceType` to be identical to `MessageType`, so both generators are guaranteed to return the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar functionality by default implementation of protocols:

```
protocol MessageSource: SequenceType {
    func messages (since : NSDate) -> Generator
}

extension MessageSource where Generator.Element: Timestamped {
    typealias MessageType = Generator.Element

    func foo() -> MessageType? {
        ...
    }
}
```